# JDBC Insert with autoincrement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm executing a query using MySQL library in java.
In my db structure there's a column called `cod_nfs` (primary key, not null and auto_increment).
Usually in every insert query I set the value to `null` and after query execution it increment last id but doing this in java give me exception.

That's the code:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO infosetdata(cod_nfs,savingDate_nfs,attributeValue_nfs,codInfoSet_nfs,codColumn_nfs,codRow_nfs) VALUES (null,'2019-01-08',?,?,?,?)";


for( String value : values ) {
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                ps.setString(1, value);
                ps.setInt(2, dataId);
                ps.setInt(3, y);
                ps.setInt(4, x);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                y++;
            }
```

How can I execute the query with auto increment id?

Comment: Can u please try removing the autu incremented column from the insert statement. Try::>   String SQL = "INSERT INTO infosetdata(savingDate_nfs,attributeValue_nfs,codInfoSet_nfs,codColumn_nfs,codRow_nfs) VALUES ('2019-01-08',?,?,?,?)";

Comment: I did it and I got this exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Field 'cod_nfs' doesn't have a default value

Comment: The correct way would be to **not** specify `cod_nfs` in the insert list. And if you get that exception, then it is not an auto increment column. Please add the DDL of the table to your question.

Comment: yeah, you're right. My administrator build the database structure and I was sure that cod_nfs was an auto_increment column. Thank you

Comment: Can you try to run the command: ALTER TABLE infosetdata MODIFY `cod_nfs` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

Answer (score 3):

Do not include the primary key column in the insert.

Also, do not prepare the statement every time. Just do it once.

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO infosetdata (savingDate_nfs,attributeValue_nfs,codInfoSet_nfs,codColumn_nfs,codRow_nfs) " 
           + "VALUES ('2019-01-08',?,?,?,?)";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
for( String value : values ) {
   ps.setString(1, value);
   ps.setInt(2, dataId);
   ps.setInt(3, y);
   ps.setInt(4, x);
   ps.executeUpdate();
   ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
   if (rs.next()) {
     int pk = rs.getInt(1);
     System.out.println("Generated PK = " + pk);
   }
   y++;
}
```

As you see, you can recover the generated PK value using [PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set a value for cod_nfs because it is already set as auto incremental. Try below:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO infosetdata(savingDate_nfs,attributeValue_nfs,codInfoSet_nfs,codColumn_nfs,codRow_nfs) VALUES ('2019-01-08',?,?,?,?)
```

If it gives error, make sure your cod_nfs column is set as auto incremental. Try running:

```
ALTER TABLE infosetdata MODIFY cod_nfs INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Thanks @Mark Rotteveel to help on that issue in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Autoincrement column should not be included
2. Prepared statement should be prepared with `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` option

For example:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO infosetdata (savingDate_nfs,attributeValue_nfs,codInfoSet_nfs,codColumn_nfs,codRow_nfs) " 
       + "VALUES ('2019-01-08',?,?,?,?)";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
for( String value : values ) {
   ps.setString(1, value);
   ps.setInt(2, dataId);
   ps.setInt(3, y);
   ps.setInt(4, x);
   ps.executeUpdate();
   ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
   if (rs.next()) {
     int pk = rs.getInt(1);
     System.out.println("Generated PK = " + pk);
  }
   y++;
}
```